# Рендер шаблона или редирект при POST koa.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa.js

Использую koa.js и возникла проблема: как можно сделать так, чтобы при получении post данных система рендерила новый шаблон или же просто редиректила.

Несколько раз пытался сделать что-то наподобие этого, но ничего не получается. Не могу понять почему.

```
var server = require('koa')(),
    path = require('path'),
    projectRoot = __dirname,
    staticRoot = path.join(projectRoot, '../public'),
    templateRoot = path.join(projectRoot, '/engine/template'),
    koaviews =  require('koa-views')(templateRoot, {default : 'swig'}),
    body = require('koa-better-body'),
    router = require('koa-router')();

server.use(require('koa-static')(staticRoot));

server.use(koaviews);

server.use(body({
    multipart: true
}));


router.get('/', function *(next) {
    console.log('GET');
    yield this.render('terminal/testlogin');

});

router.post('/', function *(next) {
    console.log('POST');
    yield this.render('terminal/terminal');
});

server.use(router.routes());

/*server.use(function *() {
    this.status = 404;
    yield this.render('service/404');

});*/

server.listen(80);
console.log('Сервер запустился. Порт - 80');
```

`get` срабатывает успешно - форма выводится, но вот на `post` данные при отправке с формы, получаю только запись в консоли и все. Страница не меняется.

Также пытался сделать так:

```
router.post('/', function *(next) {
    console.log('POST');
    this.redirect('/sign-in');
    this.status = 301;
});
```

Тоже ничего. При попытке передать дальше через `yield`

```
yield  this.redirect('/sign-in');
```

Получаю уведомление о том, что можно передавать только генераторы или промисы.

Answer (score 1):

Для перенаправлений в koa используется вот такой код:

```
var app = require('koa')(),
    router = require('koa-router')();

// Этот маршрут нужен только для того, чтобы сгенерировать
// корректный POST запрос на сервер.
router.get('/', function *() {
    this.body = '<html><head></head><body>'
        + '<form method="POST"><input type="submit" /></form>'
        + '</body></html>';
});

router.post('/', function *(){
    this.status = 301;
    this.redirect('/home');
});

router.get('/home', function *() {
    this.body = 'This is the home';
});

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(8000);
```

И этот код, что характерно, работает.

Использование

```
yield  this.redirect('/sign-in');
```

не имеет смысла, потому что `this.redirect` не возвращает ни генератор ни Promise (о чем вам и сообщает koa в тексте ошибки).

Как следствие, ваша ошибка, скорее всего, находится где-то за пределами предоставленного кода. Без **минимального** тестового случая, который приводил бы к ошибке, ничего более конкретного сказать нельзя.